# Как создать BAT файл для запуска Автотестов

Tags: java, selenium, selenide

Написал Авто тесты на языке Java используя библиотеку Селенид щас хочу создать Бат файл для запуска этих тестов не через программу Intellij а через этот файл

Answer (score 0):

Может так (`File1` вызывает `File2`)?

```
set JAVAC=Path\to\jdk\bin\javac.exe
set PROJECT=Path\to\project

call %JAVAC% %PROJECT%/File1.java
call %JAVAC% %PROJECT%/File2.java

call java -classpath . File1

pause
```

Comment: я не понял а зачем file1 вызывает file2 мне просто нужен батник который запустить мои автотесты и всё

Comment: Я привёл пример `bat` файла для компиляции `java` программы из нескольких файлов (у вас же не все классы в одном файле?) и показал, что надо запустить тот файл в котором находится класс `main`.

Comment: Добрый день если вам не сложно можете посмотреть данный метод подходить для моего проекта ссылку на Гугл диск оставлю    https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1V2ZcnRLsbBc5dg1pX_W11Nh-_Wvu3JLC